# Perl replace multiple strings simultaneously

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, replace, string-literals

Is there any way to replace multiple strings in a string?
For example, I have the string `hello world what a lovely day` and I want to replace `what` and `lovely` with something else..

```
$sentence = "hello world what a lovely day";
@list = ("what", "lovely"); # strings to replace
@replist = ("its", "bad"); # strings to replace with
($val = $sentence) =~ "tr/@list/@replist/d";
print "$val\n"; # should print "hello world its a bad day"..
```

Any ideas why it's not working?

Thanks.

Comment: Will the words always be entire words or is there the potential for patterns?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, `tr` doesn't work that way; consult `perldoc perlop` for details, but `tr` does transliteration, and is very different from substitution.

For this purpose, a more correct way to replace would be

```
# $val
$val =~ s/what/its/g;
$val =~ s/lovely/bad/g;
```

Note that "simultaneous" change is rather more difficult, but we could do it, for example,

```
%replacements = ("what" => "its", "lovely" => "bad");
($val = $sentence) =~ s/(@{[join "|", keys %replacements]})/$replacements{$1}/g;
```

(Escaping may be necessary to replace strings with metacharacters, of course.)

This is still only simultaneous in a very loose sense of the term, but it does, for most purposes, act as if the substitutions are done in one pass.

Also, it is more correct to replace `"what"` with `"it's"`, rather than `"its"`.

Answer (score 6):

Well, mainly it's not working as `tr///d` has nothing to do with your request (`tr/abc/12/d` replaces a with 1, b with 2, and removes c).  Also, by default arrays don't interpolate into regular expressions in a way that's useful for your task.  Also, without something like a hash lookup or a subroutine call or other logic, you can't make decisions in the right-hand side of a `s///` operation.

To answer the question in the title, you can perform multiple replaces simultaneously--er, in convenient succession--in this manner:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use common::sense;

my $sentence = "hello world what a lovely day";

for ($sentence) {
  s/what/it's/;
  s/lovely/bad/
}

say $sentence;
```

To do something more like what you attempt here:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use common::sense;

my $sentence = "hello world what a lovely day";

my %replace = (
  what => "it's",
  lovely => 'bad'
);

$sentence =~ s/(@{[join '|', map { quotemeta($_) } keys %replace]})/$replace{$1}/g;

say $sentence;
```

If you'll be doing a lot of such replacements, 'compile' the regex first:

```
my $matchkey = qr/@{[join '|', map { quotemeta($_) } keys %replace]}/;

...

$sentence =~ s/($matchkey)/$replace{$1}/g;
```

EDIT:

And to expand on my remark about array interpolation, you can change `$"`:

```
local $" = '|';
$sentence =~ s/(@{[keys %replace]})/$replace{$1}/g;
# --> $sentence =~ s/(what|lovely)/$replace{$1}/g;
```

Which doesn't improve things here, really, although it may if you already had the keys in an array:

```
local $" = '|';
$sentence =~ s/(@keys)/$replace{$1}/g;
```