# Regex undefined iterations replacement

Tags: regex, replace, find, pcre

My Samples

- Sample 1 `Authors: [{Steven Brown}]; Dates: [{2010}]`
- Sample 2 `Authors: [{John Hawk},{William Green},{Michael Ron}]; Dates: [{2001},{2002},{2003}]`

Matches I want to get

- Sample 1 `Steven Brown`,`2010`
- Sample 2 `John Hawk`, `William Green`, `Michael Ron`, `2001`, `2002`, `2003`

Resulted samples I want to get

- Sample 1 `Authors: <Steven Brown> & Dates: "2010"`
- Sample 2 `Authors: <John Hawk>,<William Green>,<Michael Ron> & Dates: "2001","2002","2003"`

I need to get a regex Find & Replace code that I can use in my text editor to get the *resulted samples*.

My approach to the regex code which isn't operating as I want for *Sample 2*:

- Find: `Authors: \[(\{(.*?)\}(,?))*\]; Dates: \[(\{(.*?)\}(,?))*\]`
- Replace: `Authors: <$2>$3 & Dates: "$5"$6`
- Result:

  - Sample 1 `Authors: <Steven Brown> & Dates: "2010"`
  - ***Sample 2*** `Authors: <Michael Ron> & Dates: "2003"`

As you see the resulted ***Sample 2*** gets only the last author name and the last date, **not the three**. How could I get it working for sample 2?

I'm not able to find an answer via search because unfortunately I don't know the terminology of what I'm trying to get.
Sorry if the title isn't declarative enough.

Comment: You can't do that with a single regex

Comment: Actually I'm trying to do that with a single regex. Is it impossible?

Comment: Yes, I realise you wanted just one regex, and yes it's impossible

Comment: I would use json parser for this!

Comment: @DavidO yes.. samples here could be converted to JSON

Comment: @karthikmanchala unfortunately I don't know any JSON for now!

Answer (score 0):

Although, these kind of problems cannot be solved with single regex (like Borodin said!).. your particular problem can be simplified and solved with single regex.

**Logic (another way to look at the problem)**: You could find and replace `[,{,},etc` instead of finding the iterations of keywords.

Regex to find: `([\[\]])|(;)|(\{(?=[a-zA-Z\s]))|((?<=[a-zA-Z\s])\})|(\{(?=\d))|((?<=\d)\})`

Replace:

- `$1` with `''` (empty string)
- `$2` with `\s&`
- `$3` with `<`
- `$4` with `>`
- `$5` with `"` (quotes)
- `$6` with `"` (quotes)

[Demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/oE6nY0/1)

Output:

```
 Authors: <Steven Brown> & Dates: "2010"

 Authors: <John Hawk>,<William Green>,<Michael Ron> & Dates: "2001","2002","2003"
```

Comment: I am unsure if this will work in a "simple text editor"s search and replace feature.

Comment: Me too.. but this will work with any engine compatible with PCRE :P

Comment: In my text editor, what should the replace code **Collectively** be?

Comment: I am not familiar with perl code.. but to start with.. you can create a map for replacements and use it for replacing.. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826865/perl-replace-multiple-strings-simultaneously

Comment: @karthikmanchala I am using Regex in a text editor that uses regex written in the perl taste, however, I don't write perl codes also, unfortunately! Could you please guide me for an alternative to using your methodology without using perl inherent code (just I need to know what to type in the the text editor's _replace box_).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to possibly do this with multiple regexes, and with running them multiple times -- This should work in a simple text editor that can Search/Replace on PCRE-style regexes.

All of these need to be run case-insensitive.

Search `(Authors: [a-z ,<>]*)\[?\{([a-z ]+)\}(,?.+)`, Replace `$1<$2>$3`. Repeat until nothing changes.

Search `(Dates: [0-9,"]*)\[?\{([0-9]+)\}(,?.+)`, Replace `$1"$2"$3`. Repeat until nothing changes.

Search `];` as a simple string, replace with `&` ( that is space, ampersand, space ).

Search `]` as a simple string, replace with nothing.